# how to align content at the base of the line

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I feel a little bit dummy but I get stuck while trying to align the content of two columns (inside a row) on the same base (height).

This is the code (simply html and css plus bootstrap 5):

```
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2" style="border: 1px solid; border-color: #FFFFFF;">
   <i class="fas fa-mobile-alt fa-2x" style="color: #FFFFFF;"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-10" style="border: 1px solid; border-color: #FFFFFF;">
   <span class="p-phone">Telefono e fax: +39 123456789</span>
  </div>
 </div><!-- end row -->
```

p-phone class is just a simple definition:

```
.p-phone{
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```

May you help me please?

Edit: thanks to all for the infos, so far i have been able to create a jsfiddle (but not to include bootstrap 5 files)

https://jsfiddle.net/davidep/fwcudq0y/3/

basically i'd like to have the content inside the two columns align on the same base (height)

Comment: _Can't_ really help you much at this point, because the code you have given so far, basically shows nothing at all: https://jsfiddle.net/qzur604v/ Provide a _proper_ [mre] first of all, please.

Answer (score 1):

add class **align-items-baseline** into the div of row

or add following style into the row

```
.row {
   align-items: baseline;
}
```

Comment: that's right but it is my mystake to explain what i would like to achieve. With your suggestion (really appreciated) i have the the columns aligned but i'd like to have the content of the two columns on the same base aligned (sorry my english is not the top)

Comment: I am so sorry, i can't understand that what you are trying to do

Comment: if you want the content vertically end of the line,
put align-items: end;

if you want the content vertically center of the line,
put align-items: center;

if you want the content vertically start of the line,
put align-items: start;

if you want the content vertically baseline (maximum end of the content) of the line,
put align-items: baseline;

Comment: thanks for the help first of all :) yes i would like to have both the text and the fontawesome icon at the base of the line (aligned at the bottom) not the columns that are already aligned but the content

Comment: The second method to move the content to the bottom of the line, give the CSS property 
"display: flex;" to the columns and "margin-top: auto;" to the content inside the column

Comment: That's it! thank you so much!!! solved

Comment: Most welcome....

Answer (score 0):

Davide,
In html code you have multiple ways to align text one a page.
This is for a tab: &#9
You can also use "p" to assemble a paragraph - Paragraphs are usually represented in visual media as blocks of text separated from adjacent blocks by blank lines and/or first-line indentation, but HTML paragraphs can be any structural grouping of related content, such as images or form fields.
Take care,
Ori